# unable to run my video project on client machine in c#?

Tags: c#, directx

i have made a window application in c# its play multiple videos at a time ... i used DirectX SDK june 2010... its working fine in my machine but it giving an exception in clients machine ... the machine has DirectX11 installed so it's not a problem there ... the exception i am getting is ...

```
************** Exception Text **************
Error in the application.
-2147220891 (VFW_E_UNSUPPORTED_STREAM)
at Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback.Video.Open(String fileName, Boolean autoRun)
at Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback.Video..ctor(String fileName)
at Video_Project.FormMain.FormMain_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in   D:\Video_Project\Video_Project\Form1.cs:line 240
at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

pls any one help me on this .....pls i am stuck in this for whole day

Comment: Missing a codec on the client?

Comment: so what should my client need specifically?

Comment: That depends on what the streams in your video file are encoded in. Try opening the file in Media Player and see what it tells you.

Comment: should i do something in my code? the media files are opening in normal Media Players in clients machine ..

Comment: Interesting. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsdirectshowdevelopment/thread/da96557b-110a-40e7-826f-4bd3e45cca3b seems you're not the only one.

Comment: yeah its seems like that... my videos are .mp4 format .. its been 3 days i am trying to solve but not getting any where ..

Comment: Are the filenames and paths correct, and the files exist, permissions? It seems odd that this works on your machine but not his...

Comment: the videos are set as application.startup path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check the machine's installed wmp codecs:
Go to WMP, press alt to get the menu, select Help->About... then click Tech Support Info. It will generate a report which amongst other things lists all the supported audio and video codecs.

Do this on both machines, Hopefully this should reveal the missing codec.